# Can I execute a method when an input box gets to a certain length?

Tags: vue.js, if-statement, input

I have an input box that takes a string. Can I execute a method (in vue.js) when the length of the string gets to a certain number?

something like

```
<input v-if="inputBox.length == 6 THEN runme()"...>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use watch option, you'll be able to react to data changes :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    message: '',
    inputLength : undefined
  },
  methods : {
    doSomething(){
      console.log('I did it !')
    }
  },
  watch :{
    message : function(val) {
      if(val.length>=5){
      this.inputLength = val.length
      this.doSomething(); 
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.intro {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.input-value {
  margin-top: 1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.highlight {
  color: #00d1b2;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="intro">Binding with Vue</h1>
  <div id='root' class="box">
    <label class="label">Enter text here</label>
    <input class="input is-medium" type='text' id='input' v-model='message'>
    <p class="input-value">The value of the input is: <span class="highlight">{{ inputLength }}</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, if input length is >= 5 then it will change the inputLenght value in data and execute a method.

For more informations  about this, go see :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Answer (score 2):

You can use a watcher to trigger a method when the string exceeds the length:

```js
new Vue({
  data () {
    return {
      model: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    model: {
      handler: function (value) {
        if (value.length >= 6) {
          this.trigger()
        }
      }
    }
  },
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    trigger () {
      alert('hi there')
    }
  },
  template: `<input v-model="model">` 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```